# Change default data for fonts used by SQL Server Reporting Services Report Wizard in VS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I’m using MS SQL Server Reporting Services Version 15.0.1102.675 with Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.4.6.

I’ve been adding new reports to my Report Project using the Report Wizard.

Can anyone tell me how to change the system default fonts, font sizes and colors that the wizard uses?

For example, I’d like wizard to deliver my report title in Calibri 14 bold in blue instead of Segoe UI Light 24 bold in black.

I can’t find a way to get to the defaults so I can change them.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: I think what you need to create a report template first and then use the template to design your reports

Comment: Thanks Harry.  That's a good work around.